# How to cache .cshtml layout in Sitecore MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, outputcache, sitecore-mvc

Adding output caching to all `Sitecore MVC` view renderings on a layout is possible, however code in `.cshtml` of the layout itself is always executed. Is there any way to apply `OutputCache` to layout razor views? It would be huge waste if it wasn's possible

Comment: Are your View Renderings ones that are used from outside of Sitecore or ones which are actually added as a Rendering in Sitecore within the Layouts section (which you are then adding via Presentations Details/Page Editor)?

Comment: The ones added as renderings are being cached just fine, the one we can't cache is the layout rendering (path to .chstml is set in the 'data' section of the layout item).

Answer (score 2):

You can only cache Renderings (View Renderings or Controller Renderings) in Sitecore MVC, for which caching options can be set in the `Caching` section of the rendering definition item or in the Presentation Details when the control is added.

It is not possible to cache the Layouts (located under `/sitecore/layout/Layouts`). The layouts are akin to View Master Pages, and therefore need to execute on every request in order to load the necessary controls.

If there are parts of the page you need to cache (and therefore not execute on every request) then dynamically bind it and set the the caching options (you can set this on the standard values of a base template). You can cache several controls at once by nesting them and then setting the caching on a control at a higher level, since the HTML for the entire set of controls is cached in a single entry.

Or if code needs to be present on every page then and you feel it needs to be cached then you can statically bind the renderings from the .cshtml and also set the caching options at the same time:

```razor
@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("{rendering-guid}", new { Cacheable = true })
```

You can find more information in this post about [Specify datasource item of a statically binded rendering](http://ctor.io/specify-datasource-item-of-a-statically-binded-rendering/)

Comment: "It is not possible to cache the Layouts (located under /sitecore/layout/Layouts)."

That's not true, cache configuration reference says it's possible with aspx layouts: "To instruct Web clients to cache entire pages, set DisableBrowserCaching to false, and use the ASP.NET OutputCache directive in layouts and sublayouts".

So clearly it's an ommission with Razor views. It DOESN'T make sense for Sitecore to decide whether layouts should or shouldn't be cached - it depends on situation and in most cases evaluating the whole layout on each request is a complete waste of CPU time.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't aware of that setting. BUT I have never come across a use case for caching the ENTIRE page, mainly because everything I have worked on has had some element of dynamic content. That setting makes even less sense in a Webforms scenario, where there is usually events tied together using code-behind. Like I said, wrap all your controls in a single rendering (which may hold a single placeholder to place all your controls within) and you effectively cache the whole page in the Sitecore HTML cache.

Comment: Thanks for response. I agree that usually that wouldn't fly, but we're trying to be smarter and we're downloading all the personalised parts (user avatar, status etc) over separate ajax calls. So we are able to cache the most heavy element (main page with the whole layout) VERY aggressively (even in the browser for 10 mins with max-age) and just downloading little json with personalised info, wich is much more performant. It works wonderfully in pure MVC, perf is crazy high.
I very much recommend this approach, unfortunately we can't do it without the full control over caching.

Comment: Maybe a combination of Sitecore HTML caching around the entire parent placeholder AND setting your own HTTP headers with the appropriate values. Take a look at the `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderLayout.BrowserCaching` processor in `renderLayout` and simply add your own processor after this. Prob not as fast as pure MVC but hopefully better.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the `DisableBrowserCaching` is even taken in account for MVC, the above pipeline is not hit since it is for WebForms and there seems to be no equivalent in MVC :( You might have to hook into the `mvc.requestEnd` pipeline to set your own headers or set them in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments around the community applying OutputCache to Razor Views won't be added by Sitecore.

However you could create a custom Cache based on the OutputCache and extend it yourself to potentially include layout Razor views.

This blog outlines how you could create a new 'Vary by ...' HTML cache option. If you scroll down to the Custom Cache Key Generator section he outlines the resolution is to override the GenerateCacheKeyprocessor.

His article is relating about caching data from external source but will give you the right guidance.

http://www.lightmaker.com/news/sitecore/sitecore-mvc-custom-caching-vary-by-external-data/

Comment: The razor views are cachable already IF they are part of view renderings in sitecore MVC, right? It may be set on presentation details (so outside of razor file itself).
So the problem rather is that there's no such setting for the layout file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore applies caching on the MVC Renderings with the help of processors defined in the *mvc.renderRendering* pipeline.

`SetCacheability` processor detects whether caching should be enabled based on the caching rendering parameters of the rendering and the site context.

`GenerateCacheKey` processor generates the cache key based on the caching rendering parameters of the rendering.

`RenderFromCache` processor responds with a cached output if it finds one for the given cache key.

Finally, there is `AddRecordedHtmlToCache` that caches the output when a cacheable rendering is rendered.

**How page level caching can be enabled (tested on Sitecore 8.2 Update 4)**

Let's assume that the Sitecore items representing pages inherit from a template named *Base page*

Add to the base templates of *Base page* the *Caching* template `{E8D2DD19-1347-4562-AE3F-310DC0B21A6C}` located at `/sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Sections/Caching`.

Each Sitecore page item that inherits from *Base page* now has access to the same caching fields than the renderings.

The idea is to add a new processor before `SetCacheability`.
This processor detects `layout` rendering types. 
If the associated Sitecore item has caching enabled, it will copy the caching definition to this rendering.

Code for this processor (it uses Glass Mapper but it is trivial to change):

```
public class SetPageCaching : RenderRenderingProcessor
{
    public SetPageCaching() { }

    ISitecoreContext GetSitecoreContext() => SitecoreContextFactory.Default?.GetSitecoreContext();

    public override void Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)
    {
        if (IsPageRendering(args.Rendering) && args.Rendering?.Item != null)
        {
            var caching = GetSitecoreContext()?.Cast<ICaching>(args.Rendering.Item);

            // the cast above always returns an item even if the item doesn't inherit the Caching template
            // we check Cacheable property to verify if it has been mapped. 
            // Value of false for Cacheable property means that 
            // the item doesn't inherit the "Caching" template or Cacheable prop value is false
            // we only do something for page items that are marked as cacheable
            if (caching?.Cacheable ?? false)
            {
                UpdateRenderingCachingDefinition(caching, args.Rendering.Caching);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool IsPageRendering(Rendering rendering) => rendering?.RenderingType == RenderingTypes.Layout;

    static void UpdateRenderingCachingDefinition(ICaching caching, RenderingCachingDefinition def)
    {
        if (caching == null || def == null) return;
        def.Cacheable = caching.Cacheable;
        def.VaryByData = caching.VaryByData;
        def.VaryByDevice = caching.VaryByDevice;
        def.VaryByLogin = caching.VaryByLogin;
        def.VaryByParameters = caching.VaryByParam;
        def.VaryByUser = caching.VaryByUser;
    }
}

[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true, TemplateId = "{E8D2DD19-1347-4562-AE3F-310DC0B21A6C}")]
public interface ICaching
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{3D08DB46-2267-41B0-BC52-BE69FD618633}")]
    bool Cacheable { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{F3E7E552-D7C8-469B-A150-69E4E14AB35C}")]
    bool ClearOnIndexUpdate { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{8B6D532B-6128-4486-A044-CA06D90948BA}")]
    bool VaryByData { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{C98CF969-BA71-42DA-833D-B3FC1368BA27}")]
    bool VaryByDevice { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{8D9232B0-613F-440B-A2FA-DCDD80FBD33E}")]
    bool VaryByLogin { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{3AD2506A-DC39-4B1E-959F-9D524ADDBF50}")]
    bool VaryByParam { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldId = "{0E54A8DC-72AD-4372-A7C7-BB4773FAD44D}")]
    bool VaryByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration to add this processor in the mvc pipeline (change `MyAssembly.SetPageCaching, MyAssembly` with your own type):

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <sitecore>
        <pipelines>
            <mvc.renderRendering>
                <processor type="MyAssembly.SetPageCaching, MyAssembly" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.SetCacheability, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
            </mvc.renderRendering>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```